# PHP Imagemagick, gd, эффект GLITCH

Tags: php, изображения, gd

Как сделать эффект GLITCH ?
сдвиг RGB цветов, может ?
[image: Effect glitch]

Comment: есть такая либа https://github.com/marcorubagotti/Glitch-on-the-fly-php